# Jquery get raw html?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div>
<a href="{Test}">Test</a>
</div>
```

When I do this:

```
alert($("div").html());
```

It returns:

```
<a href="%7BTest%D">Test</a>
```

How do I get the raw HTML that is not encoded?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? When I ran your scenario with v1.6.3, it came back unencoded. http://jsfiddle.net/6SWPB/

Comment: @mccow - if you run your fiddle in firefox it does what the OP describes. in IE it does not.

Comment: If you try it in firefox, it comes back encoded. I used the unescape function but when I assign the unescaped html to another div's html, it becomes encoded again.

Comment: Then what version of IE are you using? I'm using IE 9, and it also come back unencoded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alert(unescape($("div").html()));
```

Comment: However when I assign it to a different diff's html, it becomes encoded again. Can I prevent this? Ex: $("#second_div").html(unescape($("#first_div").html()));

Comment: @firebird - no it doesn't you're just getting caught out by the same problem when trying to `alert($('#second').html())` tou need to `alert(unescape($('#second').html()))`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6SWPB/2/ - check the html of the second div in firebug.